How generated-sources folder is created?
I wonder how generated-sources folder is created under the /target folder. As far as I know it is created from Open API YAML file, however, I cannot find the generated classes as components in the mentioned YAML file above. I might not understand the concept well, so please let me know if anything wrong with my understanding.
This is the structure of the repo basically:

/target under example-app is generated from the open-api.yaml. However, I cannot figure out where classes in/target under example-clients is generated from.

If you share your pom.xml we will see what is generating code

Add the openapi yaml file and an example of a class you expect to find but don't or viceversa.
